# Неизменяемость в python

Tags: python

Не могу толком понять в python тему неизменяемость.
К примеру:
a = 5
a = 10
Вывод 10, т.е. переменная a уже не 5 а 10, как-бы изменилась. Или здесь что-то другое имеется ввиду?

Comment: Воспринимайте `a` как ссылку, сначала она указывает на объект 5, затем - на объект 10. Пятерка в десятку не мутировала, просто вы "передвинули" указатель с одного объекта на другой.

Comment: @PavelKarateev: в целом верно, но слова "указатель", "ссылка" имеют большой багаж (широко используются в других языках с разными усложнёнными значениями недоступными простым смертным). В Питоне используйте слово ["имя"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding). Посмотрите на [картинки для ясности](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В среде Python-программистов есть такое изречение "В python-е все есть объект".

Когда программист присваивает что-то в переменную, то он присваивает не само значение, а ссылку на объект. В вашем примере сначала создается объект со значением `5`, берется его адрес(грубо, очень грубо) и присваивается переменной `a`. Затем создается объект в котором хранится `10`, берется его адрес и этот адрес присваивается в `a`. Далее, объект со значением `5` живет до тех пор, пока его garbage collector не решит отправить к праотцам.

Еще раз, все операции в Python-е ведутся относительно объектов. Когда говорят о `mutable` или `immutable` то имееют ввиду свойства объектов!

Возможно Вам просто непонятна концепция "указатель" и поэтому приведу аналогию из мира людей:
Когда Вы берете в руки смартфон и звоните к Ане, чтобы поговорить, то вы говорите не с номером телефона и не со смартфоном, а с Аней. Номер телефона всего лишь "указатель" на Аню. А смартфон это переменная, которая хранит указатель на Аню. И чтобы получить доступ к Ане вы используете переменнную в которой хранится номер Ани и только тогда вы получаете доступ к ней.

Comment: Вы представили усложнённую и неверную модель. [В Питоне можно проще модель использовать без всяких указателей.](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables)

Comment: @jfs: Если что-то выглядит как утка, плавает как утка и крякает как утка, то что это если не утка? Да, можно представить и без указателя. Но зачем? И ничуть не усложненную. Всему есть свое имя. По факту переменные в Python ничто иное как ссылки. В данном случае надо не упрощать до не понятно чего, а дать понятие "ссылки", которое встречается в современной программной инженерии настолько часто, что не знать и не понимать этого термина очень сложно при разработке

Comment: не путайте людей. Нажмите на ссылку в моём комментарии (вы рассказываете про модель с "коробочками", а в Питоне можно использовать модель с "именами").

Answer (score 3):

Во всех русскоязычных переводах используется терминология «изменяемый-неизменяемый». Это не самый удачный вариант, так как он вносит неоднозначность, ассоциируясь с некоей константностью. Термины "мутирующий-немутирующий" были бы уместнее и точнее отображали бы суть происходящего: может ли объект этого типа изменять свою структурность? Например: строка s = 'abcdef' - это неизменяемый тип, так как в Python нельзя, в отличие от C/C++ изменить некоторый одиночный символ в строке, например, через s[ 2 ] = 'z', не говоря уже о том, чтобы вставить символ внутрь строки. Но можно сделать s = s[ :2 ] + 'z' = s[ 3: ] и получить в результате, требуемую строку 'abzdef', только это будет совершенно другая строка, размещённая по совершенно другому адресу в памяти, а s — переустановленная ссылка на эту новую строку. Но изменить строку или её длину (её структурность) по текущей ссылке — невозможно. В этом и состоит неизменяемость объекта — это не константность, так как его значение можно изменить, но это будет уже ссылка на другой объект с этим новым значением.

Answer (score 1):

Целое число в Питоне неизменяемо (immutable). В вашем примере никакие объекты не меняются. Сначала имя `a` ссылается на объект `5`, а потом имя `a` ссылается на *другой* объект `10` (просто бирку с одного объекта на другой переместили). Вот [хорошая иллюстрация того что происходит](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#python-has-names).